# How to insert into a single auto_incremented column in SQL Server using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I've got a table with only a single auto incremented column in MS SQL Server. When I attempt to insert into it using JDBC, I get `INFO: Unable to locate non-key columns for table 'stuff' so an empty insert statement is generated` as expected and then I get
`ERROR: Incorrect syntax near ')'`.

The generated sql is: `INSERT INTO stuff () VALUES()`.

My understanding is that the SQL would need to be `INSERT INTO stuff DEFAULT VALUES`. How can I get JDBC to generate that?

I've been using `SimpleJdbcInsert.`

Comment: Do you mean _Spring JDBC_ instead of Hibernate?

Comment: Why do you need to do this specific thing with T-SQL that JDBC generates (especially if it doesn't seem capable of doing this)? You can put the command you want - and know how to write - in a stored procedure, and tell JDBC to execute that stored procedure, instead of relying on it to do the thing you need it to do...

Comment: Short of that, you could add a dummy column to the table, and insert `NULL` into it. You know, if JDBC will let you do that. Why people choose to use these brainless, half-functional and completely inflexible frameworks is beyond me.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes indeed. Thanks and edited question tags.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've currently got a sort of dummy column in there to get this working. I just figured there had to be a better way and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly do 2 things :

Have a key in my stuff table where the key is the name of the increment.
The other thing, make sure to define my object in the following way :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

and you leave it null (0) when persisting. (null if you use the Integer / Long wrappers)

In some cases the AUTO strategy is resoved to SEQUENCE rathen than to IDENTITY or TABLE, so you might want to manually set it to IDENTITY or TABLE (depending on the underlying database).